# Zapier Zap for retrieving customer data from stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, zapier

I have created a Zapier Zap with the following steps:

1. **Catch Hook (Trigger)**: A webhook which catches post requests with a param `customer_id`
2. **Find Customer (Action)**: Stripe integration which takes the `customer_id` parameter from (1) and retrieves the customer from Stripe

The setup works correctly in the Zapier setup flow, however, when I post to the endpoint from (1) I simply get a 200 return from step (1) alone. Instead I want to receive the data as returned by step (2).

Is this possible using Zapier?

Comment: You'll likely need a third step which will use the [POST action](https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations#triggers-and-actions) to send the JSON data returned from Stripe back to your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get data back directly when sending a webhook to Zapier. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753229/get-a-post-zapier-webhook-response-from-php-curl/48777653#48777653) for more info, but the idea is that your zap steps happen asynchronously instead of right away.

You can either add a 3rd step to send the result somewhere (perhaps to the server that's making the initial request to Zapier?) or, run a little webserver yourself that can reply to your initial request with the response you expect.